# A cardinal relation on Banach spaces,

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples

A very well known theorem states that if $X$ is a separable banach space, $(B_{X'},\sigma(X',X))$ is metrizable and thus both second countable and separable. Is there any example of a banach space $X$ with $d((B_{X'},\sigma(X',X)))=\aleph_0<w((B_{X'},\sigma(X',X)))$ (where $w$ stands for the topological weight of the space)? Can anyone point me to a reference?

I only know this cannot happen if $X$ is reflexive, since in that case $(B_{X'},\sigma(X',X))$ is an Eberlein compact and thus strongly monolithic.

Comment: Isn't $d(X) = w((B_{X'}, \sigma(X',X))$? I thought that was used in the proof of the separable case.

Comment: Nice to see "monolithic" again (I did some work on monolithic hyperspaces for my PhD)...

Comment: Maybe $X= C(\beta \Bbb R)$ will work?